# sum two or more columns in mysql table but leave out the null field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to sum two or three columns, but if any column is NULL then it should not affect the value of SUM.
As i get NULL if columns are added all together.

Here is the example of table i am trying to work on.

```
id   col1 col2   col3  total
1     2     3    5
2     10    5    NULL
3     2     NULL NULL
```

This is the query i tried.

```
SELECT id,col1,col2,col3, (col1+col2+col3) AS Total FROM test_table;
```

This Query works perfectly fine if there is no NULL column, but if there is any null column then number added with null becomes null and i get null in result..

Below is the Result Screen Shot i added.

[image]

in above image i get NULL in Total column if any column in sum has null.
But results should be like  10,15,2 respected to there id's.

Comment: coalesce each column value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
SELECT id,col1,col2,col3, (IFNULL(col1,0)+IFNULL(col2,0)+IFNULL(col3,0)) AS Total
FROM test_table;
```

Comment: Thankyou. i was actually asked this question in my interview today which ofcourse i could not answer.. and i tried to find out on internet but i guess i did not put right words to search thats why i posted the question.
THanks, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Use coalesce to replace null values with 0.  I prefer `coalesce`. In my experience it is database agnostic, where as `isnull`, `ifnull`, `nvl` and others are specific to the database.

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3, (coalesce(col1,0)+ coalesce(col2,0)+ coalesce(col3,0)) as total from test_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would need to use IsNull(Column, 0) to ensure it is always 0 at minimum.

SELECT col1, col2, col3, sum(isnull(col1,0) + isnull(col2,0) + isnull(col3,0)) AS Total FROM test_table group by id;

Answer (score -1):

Modify your select statement to exclude nulls.